# Boost customizable entry point: custom main()

Tags: c++, boost

I'm trying to create a custom `main()` using `boost::unit_test` following https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/adv_scenarios/shared_lib_customizations/entry_point.html:

`MyClass.h` defines a `class` `MyClass` which has a simple function `add(x,y)`.

Now in `test_MainClass.cpp:

```
#define BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK
#include <boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp>
#include "MyClass.h"


BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(constructor_test) {
  MyClass ms;
  BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(ms.add(2, 3), 8);

  system("pause");
}
```

and in `my_main.cpp`

```
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE test my_main
#define BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK
#define BOOST_TEST_NO_MAIN
#include <boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp>

// entry point:
int main(int argc, char* argv[], char* envp[])
{
    return boost::unit_test::unit_test_main(&init_unit_test, argc, argv);

}
```

which gives a lot of errors:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  E0904   a function declared 'dllimport' may not be defined  MyBoost C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_62_0\boost\test\impl\test_tools.ipp  397 
Error (active)  E0904   a function declared 'dllimport' may not be defined  MyBoost C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_62_0\boost\test\impl\unit_test_main.ipp  184 
Error (active)  E1389   redeclaration cannot add dllexport/dllimport to "boost::test_tools::tt_detail::equal_impl" (declared at line 424 of "C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_62_0\boost\test\impl\test_tools.ipp")   MyBoost C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_62_0\boost\test\tools\old\impl.hpp   117 
Error (active)  E1389   redeclaration cannot add dllexport/dllimport to "boost::unit_test::unit_test_main" (declared at line 184 of "C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_62_0\boost\test\impl\unit_test_main.ipp")   MyBoost C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_62_0\boost\test\unit_test.hpp    45
```

Comment: The example shows the include of `#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>`, not `#include <boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp>`. Does it solve the problem to include the correct header?

Comment: no, unfortunately it's all the same